# How can I make this picture always stay in the center of the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build my own website. My PAGE1 is split into 3 columns. In the third column I want to place a picture in the center, but horizontally only. I am wondering why "margin-left:auto;" and "margin-right:auto;" don't do the job. Please help me centering this picture.

This is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div id="PAGE1" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="backgroundDiv1"></div>
        <div id="backgroundDiv2"></div>
        <div style="height:100%" class="row">
            <div id="reihe1"class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div id="reihe2" class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div id="reihe3"class="col-md-6">
                <div id="googleDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="google+"><img id="googleplus" src="google+.png"></div>
                <div id="titel">
                    <p>*******</p>
                    <p>*******</p>
                    <p id="designer">*********</p>
                    <img src="pfeil.png" id="arrow">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#PAGE1{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#backgroundDiv1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#848484;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom:0;
    border-top-right-radius:700px;
    border-top-left-radius:200px;
    border-right: solid black 20px; 
}
#backgroundDiv2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#742B22;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom:0;
    border-top-right-radius:400px;
    border-top-left-radius:200px;
    border-right: solid black 20px;
}
#titel{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:450%;
    color:#222222;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
#designer{
    font-size: 0.6em!important;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
#arrow{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the width of the image isn't declared.  Margin:auto only works when the width of the object is known, either via a `width:Npx` CSS tag or in the case of an img tag, a width attribute.

Comment: I just added the css atribute "width:100px;". Still  got the same problem though.

Comment: The parent div may also need a width attribute as well.  Its been a while since I've fiddled with this sort of problem, but I do recall that the "magic" of `margin:auto` only works when the width is explicitly declared.

Comment: Well, the row the picture is placed should have a width, because of the class="col-md-6".

Comment: Apply Display: block; margin: 0 auto;  on your image

Answer (score 0):

Either apply a width to the img or wrap the image in a div and apply text-align:center to the div.